# Is a single node after dividing a graph still considered a subset?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, treenode, undirected-graph

For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty9LG.png)

Dividing between A and B:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9768.png)

Would DAC and B be considered two subsets?

I am trying to create two subsets from an initial graph of 4 nodes.

Comment: I would say that it is. A set can even be empty - obviously dividing beyond that point is unrewarding :)

Answer (score 0):

"A graph G is a finite nonempty set of objects called vertices together with a possibly empty set of unordered pairs of distinct vertices of G called edges."

"A graph H is a subgraph of a graph G if V(H) is a subset of V(G) and E(H) is a subset of E(G)"

-- both from Graph & Digraphs 2nd ed by Chartrand & Lesniak.

DAC and B are both subgraphs of the input graph. Neither is a subset since a graph isn't a set but a pair of sets as defined above. Note as per the definitions, a graph can have no edges, but must have at least one vertex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by subset you mean **subgraph**.

The answer is **yes**, a single isolated node is still a subgraph of the graph that contains that node.

Subgraphs can even be empty. The empty graph is a subgraph of all graphs.